C++ / winRT: Using the MediaPlayer API
I'm trying to use the MediaPlayer API in the most simple way. All I want to do is play back an audio file (and possibly get a notification when it's done).
Unfortunately, this forces me to use winRT and asynchronous operations, which I'm not very familiar with. So I'm despairing over the simple task of opening a file and passing it to the media player. I invested many hours and tried various approaches, but it still doesn't work.
Here's what I got at the moment:
using namespace winrt::Windows;
auto async = Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
async.Completed([] (auto const & res, Foundation::AsyncStatus const status) {
    if (status == Foundation::AsyncStatus::Completed) {
        auto source = Media::Core::MediaSource::CreateFromStorageFile(res.GetResults());
        Media::Playback::MediaPlayer player;
        player.Source(source);
        player.Play();
    }
});

Please note that I actually don't care about asynchronous ops. It's fine in this context to wait for a sec for the file opening. But a simple async.get() or wait_for() asserts in debug builds and IIRC can create problems in release builds.
While the above code compiles and runs, playback never starts. Watching the global Windows error variable, I get various errors from MediaSource::CreateFromStorageFile(), depending on which file I'm trying to open: 1008 ("An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.") and 14007 ("The requested lookup key was not found in any active activation context."). Very cryptic.
So my question is actually twofold: Am I doing the file opening right or is there a better/simpler way? What's up with those errors and how do I successfully open local audio files?
Update:
I got so confused with all the winRT async stuff, that I made a silly mistake in the above code. The playback actually works, when I don't throw the MediaPlayer away immediately after starting it... And it works despite of the cryptic errors.
I'm still leaving this question open because I'm still interested in the proper way to open files.

Please show a [mcve].

@IInspectable I think I did. What's wrong with it?

I cannot compile it. There's no entry point, for example.

Oh OK, but by that measure you'd have to flag at least 90% of SO posts. Actually, there's nothing to reproduce here anymore. I just want an expert to chip in regarding the most simple way to open a file in winRT, especially when not caring about async operation. I still can't believe that it took me hours to arrive at that little snippet....

"by that measure you'd have to flag at least 90% of SO posts" - Yes. If you aren't doing that you're probably new to this place. Regardless, there are several options you have, and applicability depends on the circumstances of the remaining code. Which just means: No complete sample, no help.

Async in C++/WinRT is meant to be done with coroutines:
winrt::fire_and_forget
MainWindow::Button_Click(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    auto file = co_await Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
    auto source = Media::Core::MediaSource::CreateFromStorageFile(file);
    Media::Playback::MediaPlayer player;
    player.Source(source);
    player.Play();
    co_await winrt::resume_after(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    // player will go out of scope now and stop playing
}

Sometimes you may want to block. Just move to a background thread:
winrt::fire_and_forget
MainWindow::Button_Click(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    // now we can block
    auto file = Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filename).get();
}

or without coroutines
void MainWindow::Button_Click(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    winrt::Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync([](auto&&...){
        // now we can block
        auto file = Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filename).get();
    });
}

The docs are reasonably good. It's a good idea to try site searching them i.e. google site:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis async when you don't know the idiomatic thing to do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2

You can also use IIFEs to stop the async spreading up the call stack [&]() -> winrt::fire_and_forget { co_await GetFileFromPathAsync(filename); }();

You cannot pass a (const) reference into a coroutine. That's a latent bug turning into a real issue at the first suspension point.

I was trying to avoid introducing co_await into a huge legacy project just for this one tiny issue. So thank you for the ThreadPool::RunAsync solution, hadn't seen this one before. Behaviorwise, this seems to pretty similar to my async.Completed solution. Control flow will leave the surrounding function before the async part is done. So it's not truly synchronous. MS docs say to just use get(), but in a previous attempt, that mysteriously lead to problems with hosted WebView2 browsers (which are also based on  that async callback approach) in a completely different part of our UI.

I agree that the MS docu isn't too shabby in this case, but it's still hard to get started, especially in pure C++ and without co-routines. There seem to be multiple approaches in different language projections and whatnot. Most examples (or rather tiny snippets) are in C# or managed C++. And when you search SO or other sites, people mix it all up and throw some ppltasks on top.

@Simpleton PPL Tasks work well with WinRT's IAsync* as well. If you're looking for documentation WIL's wiki is fairly complete. Plus, the async support for the WinRT has been gradually phased out of C++/WinRT and into the WIL, so that's a useful library to know about when doing any sort of WinRT work.

@IInspectable can I ask what parts of WIL you rely on? What parts do you recommend others use?

For correctness: resume_foreground and apartment_variable. For convenience pretty much everything else. The error-handling helpers (in combination with the RAII wrappers) are useful for any sort of Windows programming, but there's a lot more you'll eventually find helpful.
